# Read multiple file to export to one CSV

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, filereader

I'm trying to read multiple files via a form. Afterwars I want to store them in one CSV-file.

Currently the data in state is empty because the FileReader is not finished reading yet, but I cant seems to figure out an elegant option. Can anyone help?

My code so far:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = { data : null, files : null }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      files: event.target.files
    })
  }
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.retrieveFiles()
    this.exportToCSV()
  }

  retrieveFiles = () => {
    this.setState({ data: [] })
    Array.from(this.state.files).forEach(
      (file) => {
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.filename = file.name
        reader.onloadend = this.readFiles
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8")
      }
    )
  }
  readFiles = (event) => {
    this.setState((state) => {
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var data = state.data.concat([{
        filename : event.target.filename, 
        content: parser.parseFromString(event.target.result, "text/xml")
      }])
      return { data : data }
    })
  }
  exportToCSV = (data) => {
    console.log(this.state.data)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="xbpm-tracer">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h1>Upload file(s)</h1>
          <label>
            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={this.handleChange} multiple />
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does all the file have same type of dataset in terms of columns? If yes then you can merge the data of all files in one single array and then use that array to save it in csv. You can use any libraries like exceljs or convert-array-to-csv to save data in csv.

Comment: That is the case. How would you do that?